# Trouble setting up dynamic bit-rate RTMP streaming via Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, rtmp, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to set up RTMP dynamic streaming via Coudfront but getting "Error loading stream: Manifest not found or invalid" in JWPlayer.

The link to the webiste is http://testiranje7.tk/video_cdn.html and the code that is trying to load the .smil file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<head>

    <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/H5ZwPmjuEe.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mediaplayer">Loading the player...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
        playlist: [{
            sources: [{
                file: "http://oregonvedro.s3.amazonaws.com/videos_playlist.smil"
                }]
            }],
            primary: "flash"
   });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The .smil file is in Amazon S3 bucket and it holds the following code:

```
<smil>
  <head>
    <meta base="rtmp://s2as2xpom4wy97.cloudfront.net:1935/cfx/st/"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <switch>
        <video src="HD_MOV_2_1600.mp4" system-bitrate="1600000" />
        <video src="HD_MOV_2_1200.mp4" system-bitrate="1200000" />
        <video src="HD_MOV_2_800.mp4" system-bitrate="800000" />
        <video src="HD_MOV_2_400.mp4" system-bitrate="400000" />
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>
```

I got the syntax from a site where dynamic streaming appears to be working, but it doesn't work on my site and I can't figure out why....

Answer (score 1):

I copied your html file and smil file and saved them in a same directory.
Then instead of loading the playlist file through http protocal i.e.

file:"http://oregonvedro.s3.amazonaws.com/videos_playlist.smil",

I loaded it  as

file: "videos_playlist.smil"

and it worked fine in my computer.

To run it in a domain/ip you might have to use a premium license of jwplayer.

Comment: That's interesting.... I thought it was something wrong with the links... I'll look into JWPlayer licensing